# Javascript - Converting string to number in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, mapping

I have an array of objects called `reports` that has an object `reportId` that is currently returning as a string. I would like to convert that object `reportId` to integers. How can I do this with an array of objects?

I've attempted to accomplish this with mapping. and using `parseInt` but I am not having success.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
let reports = [ {reportId: "21", title: "Online", code: "ON" }, {reportId: "11", title: "Retail", code: "RE" }, {reportId: "61", title: "Walk-in", code: "WI" } ]



 let ids = reports.reportId.split(',').map(function (item) {
        return parseInt(item, 10);
    });
    
console.log(ids)
```

I am expecting a return of a new array that wil llist `reportId` as numbers instead of a string such as: `[ 21, 11, 61 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating things; you just need to map each entry in `reports` to its `reportId` property and convert that to an integer

```js
let reports = [ 
  {reportId: "21", title: "Online", code: "ON" },
  {reportId: "11", title: "Retail", code: "RE" },
  {reportId: "61", title: "Walk-in", code: "WI" } 
]

let ids = reports.map(function (item) {
  return parseInt(item.reportId, 10);
});
    
console.log(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map over reports, not reports.reportId.split. In fact, reports is an array, it does not have a named property called "reportId", only the objects inside the array have it.

```js
const reports = [ {reportId: "21", title: "Online", code: "ON" }, {reportId: "11", title: "Retail", code: "RE" }, {reportId: "61", title: "Walk-in", code: "WI" } ];

const reportIds = reports.map(({ reportId }) => parseInt(reportId, 10));

console.log(reportIds);
```

Side note: use const over let, almost always!